# XTemplate creation not working

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Here the code which i used to implement a Xtemplate, But it doesnt showing any any values even though the JSON responce success

**XTemplate**

```
    var tab = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        id: 'itemList',
        flex:1,
        width: '100%',
        items: [{
            id: 'itemList',
            width: '100%',
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<div style="margin:0px;" ><table style="margin:0px;padding:0px;height:40px;" width="100%" ><tr><td style="padding:2px 5px;width:90%;"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{itemImage}"/>{itemImage}</td><td style="padding:2px 10px;width:10%;"><img src="resources/img/arrow.png" onclick="invitefriends{\'{userId}\',this)"/></td></tr></table></div>', {
                    getDifference: function (t365, tytd) {
                        return parseFloat(t365 - tytd).toFixed(2);
                    },
                    getCvsWidth: function () {
                        //return screen.width - 210;
                        if ((window.innerWidth - 210) < 350) {
                            return 350;
                        } else {
                            return window.innerWidth - 210;
                        }
                    }
                })

        }]
    }
```

**JSON method**

function viewgiftlist()
{

```
Ext.Viewport.mask({ xtype: 'loadmask' });
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: App.gvars.apiurl + 'ShowItems/userID='+App.gvars.userid, 
    method: "GET",
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    success: function (response) {
        var respObjs = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                Ext.Viewport.mask({ xtype: 'loadmask' });
                 if(respObjs.showItems[0].response=="Success")
                 {
                  IsLoggedIn1 = "true";
                  Ext.getCmp('itemList').setData(respObjs.showItems);
                  Ext.Viewport.unmask();
                 }
                 if(respObjs.showItems[0].response=="failed")
                 {
                  Ext.Viewport.unmask();
                 Ext.Msg.alert("Alert!","No items found! Please add item.");
                 }
    },
    failure: function (response) {
          Ext.Viewport.unmask();       
      var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
          Ext.Msg.alert("Error",response.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

What wrong with my XTemplate creation please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this below..

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    width: 320,
    height: 290,
    id : 'itemList',
    itemTpl: ['<div style="margin:0px;background:#fff;" >'+
              '<table style="margin:0px;padding:0px;height:40px;" width="100%" >'+
              '<tr><td style="padding:2px 5px;width:90%;"><span><img src=""/>'+
              '</span><span>{itemName}<br>{itemDesc}</span></td>'+
              '<td style="padding:2px 10px;width:10%;">'+
              '<img src="resources/img/arrow.png" />'+
              '</td></tr></table></div>'].join(),
    listeners : {
        itemtap: function (list, index, item, record, senchaEvent) {
            if (senchaEvent.event.target.nodeName == 'IMG') {
                 var data = record.getData();
                 var itemId = data.itemId;
                 var itemPurchased = data.itemPurchased;
                // Call viewgiftdetails method and pass itemId and itemPurchased 
            }
        }
    }
});
```